# drupal 6: how to modify the display of the comment module

Tags: drupal-6, module, comments, hook

Before posting comments a message is shown:

```
Login or register to post comments
```

I want to modify the output of the 2 links "login" and "register", mainly I want to add some classes to the  links to format it nicely with some img. buttons of different colors

I really need to "tell" the output to put  and , and by default doesn't have no class....

I know it can be done with some hook or something but I can't find no info about that ...

Answer (score 1):

The piece responsible for that line is locate in `theme_comment_post_forbidden` in drupal_root/modules/comment/comment.module

it looks like this

```
function theme_comment_post_forbidden($node) {
  global $user;
  static $authenticated_post_comments;

  if (!$user->uid) {
    if (!isset($authenticated_post_comments)) {
      // We only output any link if we are certain, that users get permission
      // to post comments by logging in. We also locally cache this information.
      $authenticated_post_comments = array_key_exists(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, user_roles(TRUE, 'post comments') + user_roles(TRUE, 'post comments without approval'));
    }

    if ($authenticated_post_comments) {
      // We cannot use drupal_get_destination() because these links
      // sometimes appear on /node and taxonomy listing pages.
      if (variable_get('comment_form_location_'. $node->type, COMMENT_FORM_SEPARATE_PAGE) == COMMENT_FORM_SEPARATE_PAGE) {
        $destination = 'destination='. rawurlencode("comment/reply/$node->nid#comment-form");
      }
      else {
        $destination = 'destination='. rawurlencode("node/$node->nid#comment-form");
      }

      if (variable_get('user_register', 1)) {
        // Users can register themselves.
        return t('<a href="@login">Login</a> or <a href="@register">register</a> to post comments', array('@login' => url('user/login', array('query' => $destination)), '@register' => url('user/register', array('query' => $destination))));
      }
      else {
        // Only admins can add new users, no public registration.
        return t('<a href="@login">Login</a> to post comments', array('@login' => url('user/login', array('query' => $destination))));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I suggest modifying your theme's template.php and adding a new function `phptemplate_comment_post_forbidden($node)` where you'll copy the contents of `theme_comment_post_comments` and do the necessary modifications.